# How do I dynamically create functions that are accessible in a parent scope?

Tags: function, powershell, dynamic, scope

Here is an example:

```
function ChildF()
{
  #Creating new function dynamically
  $DynFEx =
@"
  function DynF()
  {
    "Hello DynF"
  }
"@
  Invoke-Expression $DynFEx
  #Calling in ChildF scope Works
  DynF 
}
ChildF
#Calling in parent scope doesn't. It doesn't exist here
DynF
```

I was wondering whether you could define DynF in such a way that it is "visible" outside of ChildF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The other solutions are better answers to the specific question.  That said, it's good to learn the most general way to create global variables:

```
# inner scope
Set-Variable -name DynFEx -value 'function DynF() {"Hello DynF"}' -scope global

# somewhere other scope
Invoke-Expression $dynfex
DynF
```

Read 'help about_Scopes' for tons more info.

Answer (score 14):

Another option would be to use the `Set-Item -Path function:global:ChildFunction -Value {...}`

Using `Set-Item`, you can pass either a string or a script block to value for the function's definition.

Comment: Passing a _script block_ to `-Value` works great, but passing a _string_ does _not_ work as intended: while `Set-Item` accepts it, invoking the function then merely _echoes_ the definition string with the curly braces stripped. You can work around that with `&`, but it's awkward and I'm not sure if it has side effects (e.g., `set-item function:foo "& { 'arg 0: ' + `$args[0] } `@args"; foo 'hi'` - better to use `Invoke-Expression` if you need to build the function body in a string.

Answer (score 9):

You can scope the function with the `global` keyword:

```
function global:DynF {...}
```

Comment: In the given code above, `function global:DynF { ... }` probably makes more sense. ;-).

Answer (score 2):

A more correct and functional way to do this would be to return the function body as a script block and then recompose it.

```
function ChildF() {
    function DynF() {
        "Hello DynF"
    }
    return ${function:DynF}
}
$DynFEx = ChildF
Invoke-Expression -Command "function DynF { $DynFEx }"
DynF
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Richard's post.  Kept having issues doing this simple thing.  I revised for passing a function from local to remote.

```
#Method 1 Load the function from disk    
$getCert = gc 'C:\MyScripts\getCert.ps1'
Invoke-Command $RemoteSrv -ScriptBlock {Set-Variable -name DefFN -value ($Args -join "`n") -scope global ; Invoke-Expression $DefFn } -ArgumentList $getCert
    
#Method 2 Load the function from local definition of function
Invoke-Command $RemoteSrv -ScriptBlock {Set-Variable -name DefFN -value ($Args -join "`n") -scope global ; Invoke-Expression $DefFn } -ArgumentList ('Function GetCert {'+(Get-Command GetCert).Definition+'}')

#Remote server now has function
Invoke-Command $RemoteSrv -ScriptBlock {getcert stackoverflow.com}

URL        : stackoverflow.com
Expires    : 12/14/2021 8:07:08 AM
SAN        : DNS Name=*.askubuntu.com, DNS Name=.....
Thumbprint : ec0055be478411bafe98d11d63a5c9279ff0e173
IP         : 151.101.193.69
Handle     : 2866249748176
Issuer     : CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US
Subject    : CN=*.stackexchange.com
```