# Add PowerShell function to the parent scope

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have some PowerShell helper functions in a file. I'd like to make them available to the scope of another file that I am writing, but not pollute the global scope.

Helpers.ps1

```
function global:Helper1
{
    # this function pollutes the global scope
}
function Helper2
{
    # this function is not visible to the Utility.ps1 file.
}
```

Utilities.ps1

```
&{
    ./Helpers.ps1
    function global:Utility1
    {
        Helper1
    }
    function global:Utility2
    {
        Helper2
    }
}
```

I found this question:
[How do I dynamically create functions that are accessible in a parent scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123634/how-do-i-dynamically-create-functions-that-are-accessible-in-a-parent-scope) but the answers discuss adding functions to the global scope. What I really want to do is make the Helper functions from one PS1 file available to a calling PS1 file, *without* polluting the global scope with the helpers.

I want to avoid defining the functions as variables, which is possible with Set-Variable and the -Scope parameter. The closest I've seen (from the linked thread) is using Set-Item in the function: drive.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit: here is the solution expanded from Mike's answer**

Helpers.ps1

```
function Helper
{
}
```

Utilities.ps1

```
&{
    function global:Utility
    {
        . ./Helpers.ps1
        Helper1
    }
}
```

Using the dot-source syntax to load Helpers.ps1 puts it's contents in the scope of the Utility function. Putting Helpers.ps1 outside the Utility function causes it to be in the &{...} scope but that scope ends once the functions are defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you dot-source a .ps1 file in a function, the definitions that are in the ps1 file are not global, unless the function was itself dot-sourced.

Comment: I didn't know about dot-sourcing. I'm new to PS. Thanks muchly!

Answer (score 7):

You can use this snippet in the Utilities.ps1 file. What we do is get all current functions then we dot source the helpers. We then make a diff of the before and after functions. From the diff we recreate the functions in the global scope.

```
$beforeFunctions = ls function:
. .\helpers.ps1
$afterFunctions = ls function:
$functionDiff = @(Compare-Object $beforeFunctions $afterFunctions)
foreach($diffEntry in $functionDiff){
    $func = $diffEntry.InputObject
    invoke-expression "function global:$($func.Name) { $($func.definition) }"
}
```