# In Powershell, how to set variable values within a function and have that value available in the parent scope?

Tags: function, variables, powershell, scope

I am trying to set the values for some variables using a function. My code is below:

```
$BackupFile = $null
$TaskSequenceID = $null
$OSDComputerName = $null
$capturedWimPath = $null

Function Set-OsToBuild 
{
  switch ($OsToBuild)
  {
    "Win7x64"
        { 
            $BackupFile = "Win7x64-SP1.wim"
            $TaskSequenceID = "WIN7X64BC"
            $OSDComputerName = "Ref-Win7x64"
            $capturedWimPath = "$($PathToMdtShare)\Captures\$BackupFile"
        }
  }
}
```

The problem is that these values for $BackupFile, $TaskSequenceID, $OSDComputerName and $capturedWimPath are blank/null outside of this function.

What is the proper way to do this? I want to set these values within this function and have those values available later on in the script, in the parent scope.

Comment: The related links on the side show this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123634/how-do-i-dynamically-create-functions-that-are-accessible-in-a-parent-scope?rq=1 to create global scope variables and you could always return a custom object of this information

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The variables are created in your function's `local`-scope. Those variables are deleted when your function is done.

> ```
> Global: 
>     The scope that is in effect when Windows PowerShell
>     starts. Variables and functions that are present when
>     Windows PowerShell starts have been created in the
>     global scope. This includes automatic variables and
>     preference variables. This also includes the variables, aliases,
>     and functions that are in your Windows PowerShell
>     profiles.
>
> Local:  
>     The current scope. The local scope can be the global 
>     scope or any other scope. 
>
> Script: 
>     The scope that is created while a script file runs. Only
>     the commands in the script run in the script scope. To
>     the commands in a script, the script scope is the local
>     scope.
> ```

Source: [about_Scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx)

If you need the variables to be available for the script, then write them to the `script` scope.

```
$BackupFile = $null
$TaskSequenceID = $null
$OSDComputerName = $null
$capturedWimPath = $null

Function Set-OsToBuild 
{
  switch ($OsToBuild)
  {
    "Win7x64"
        { 
            $script:BackupFile = "Win7x64-SP1.wim"
            $script:TaskSequenceID = "WIN7X64BC"
            $script:OSDComputerName = "Ref-Win7x64"
            $script:capturedWimPath = "$($PathToMdtShare)\Captures\$BackupFile"
        }
  }
}
```

If you would like to keep the values for whole sessions (until you close the powershell-process), then you should use the `global` scope.

```
$global:BackupFile = $null
$global:TaskSequenceID = $null
$global:OSDComputerName = $null
$global:capturedWimPath = $null

Function Set-OsToBuild 
{
  switch ($OsToBuild)
  {
    "Win7x64"
        { 
            $global:BackupFile = "Win7x64-SP1.wim"
            $global:TaskSequenceID = "WIN7X64BC"
            $global:OSDComputerName = "Ref-Win7x64"
            $global:capturedWimPath = "$($PathToMdtShare)\Captures\$BackupFile"
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The powershell `about_scope` [help document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) is what you want to read for this.

Specifically this section:

> Windows PowerShell Scopes
>
> ```
> Scopes in Windows PowerShell have both names and numbers. The named
> scopes specify an absolute scope. The numbers are relative and reflect
> the relationship between scopes.
>
>
> Global: 
>     The scope that is in effect when Windows PowerShell
>     starts. Variables and functions that are present when
>     Windows PowerShell starts have been created in the
>     global scope. This includes automatic variables and
>     preference variables. This also includes the variables, aliases,
>     and functions that are in your Windows PowerShell
>     profiles. 
>
> Local:  
>     The current scope. The local scope can be the global 
>     scope or any other scope. 
>
> Script: 
>     The scope that is created while a script file runs. Only
>     the commands in the script run in the script scope. To
>     the commands in a script, the script scope is the local
>     scope.
>
> Private:
>     Items in private scope cannot be seen outside of the current
>     scope. You can use private scope to create a private version
>     of an item with the same name in another scope.        
>
>
> Numbered Scopes:
>     You can refer to scopes by name or by a number that
>     describes the relative position of one scope to another.
>     Scope 0 represents the current, or local, scope. Scope 1
>     indicates the immediate parent scope. Scope 2 indicates the
>     parent of the parent scope, and so on. Numbered scopes
>     are useful if you have created many recursive
>     scopes.
> ```

So depending on your exact needs you could use any one of the following I believe.

1. `$global:BackupFile = "Win7x64-SP1.wim"`
2. `$script:BackupFile = "Win7x64-SP1.wim"`
3. `$1:BackupFile = "Win7x64-SP1.wim"`

Answer (score 1):

In order to set `$BackupFile` outside, your function should write to `$script:$BackupFile`.

But there's a catch! If your script is called (using `&`, it doesn't happen when dot-sourcing) from another script, then `$BackupFile` will be inherited from caller but `$script:$BackupFile` will be empty. So you should read from `$BackupFile` but write to `$script:$BackupFile`. Also beware of syntax like `$script:BackupFile += ".bin"`, because it reads from incorrect variable.

A possible workaround to avoid pitfalls would be to begin the function with `$script:BackupFile = $BackupFile`.